# How to retrieve all the values Stored in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift3, nsuserdefaults

I am creating a Save button where the user clicks and stores the information using `NSUserDefaults`. When the user loads the app again, and clicks Show button, all the information stored before should display.  For example

Monday User inserts value 5 times: 20 , 30 ,40 ,50 ,60

Tuesday nothing.

Wednesday nothing.

Thursday same user inserts: 30, 20, 50, 80

Friday values are:  40, 20

Now on Saturday when the user click show then the data should display:
20, 30,40,50,60,30,20,50,80,40,20

SO far my coding is:

```
@IBOutlet weak var dayTB: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var numTB: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var showLabel: UILabel! // displays all the values stored

var Money = 0
@IBAction func saveBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    Money += 1
    var MoneyNumberString:String = String(format: "Dollars:%i", Money)
    self.showLabel.text = (string: MoneyNumberString)
    let defaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard 
    defaults.set(MoneyNumberString, forKey: "money")
    defaults.synchronize() 
}

 @IBAction func showbtnact(_ sender: Any) {
    let defaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var money = defaults.value(forKey: "money") as? String
    showLabel.text! = money!
}
```

Hope there is a solution for this problem :) Thanks

Comment: I just edited my code, as there was a mistake

Comment: While this isn't codereview.SE, I have a thing or two to point out: you shouldn't begin variable/constant names with a capital letter (regarding `var Money = 0`), don't force unwrap values with `!` unless you're absolutely certain that they won't ever be `nil` (regarding `money!`) and there's no point force unwrapping `showLabel.text!` while using the setter. Just `showLabel.text = ...` will work. Also, if you're not mutating properties there's no reason declaring them as variables, e.g. `var money` and `var MoneyNumberString` could instead be declared as constants with `let`.

Comment: Hi @xoudini , I am able to fetch the record, but the last saved one, I want to retrieve all the info that was saved before and display. It doesnt display all the values as expected. Any other approach? Thank you

Comment: You are not storing all values in UserDefaults. You are only saving a single value and that overwrites the previous value. 1) You need to update and store an array. 2) Don't use UserDefaults to save data.

Comment: @rmaddy , thanks, is there any example for the solution I can refer too. thanks once again

Comment: I have very limited experience  with swift and xcode. So thats the reason I took the NSUserdefault approach.

Comment: What you're doing in `saveBtn(_:)` is replacing the value every time the button is pressed. What you need to do is manipulate an array that you store in `NSUserDefaults`, or alternatively look into Core Data if you need to store larger amounts of data.

Comment: You could take a look at the documentation and try to figure out an approach with an array: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save values, what you need to do is:

```
            var ary_Values = NSMutableArray()

            if  UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "money") != nil
            {
                let arr = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "money") as! NSArray

                for oldObj in arr
                {
                    ary_Values.add(oldObj)
                }

                ary_Values.add(self.showLabel.text)
            }

            UserDefaults.standard.set(ary_Values, forKey: "money")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```